# Forwarding an iterator

Tags: ruby

I have class (highly simplified for the sake of this discussion)

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @myrecs = %w(a b c d)
  end
  def each_rec
    @myrecs.each {|r| yield(r)}
  end
end
```

and use it as

```
x = MyClass.new
x.each_rec { |r| .... }
```

Since my method `each_rec` basically does just a `myrecs.each`, I wanted to define somehow that `each_rec` just forwards to `each`. I can achieve the desired effect by explicitly passing the block, i.e.

```
def each_rec(&block)
  @myrecs.each(&block)
end
```

but I wonder wether it is also possible to achieve my goal without having the block as explicit parameter. I tried the following approaches without success:

(1) Exploit the fact that `each` returns an Enumerator when called without a block:

```
  def each_rec
    @myrecs.each
  end
```

(2) Create an Enumerator:

```
   def each_rec
     @myrecs.enum_for(:each)
   end
```

In both cases, I did not get an error, but the block passed to `each_rec` was simply not entered.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, if you call [`Proc.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-c-new) without a block inside a method that received a block, it'll convert that method's passed block to a proc. So, you can do:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @myrecs = %w(a b c d)
  end
  def each_rec
    @myrecs.each(&Proc.new)
  end
end

x = MyClass.new
x.each_rec { |r| puts r }
```

and now, you no longer need an explicit parameter to your `each_rec` method. Now, however, you must supply a block to the method, or get an ArgumentError ("tried to create Proc object without a block"). We can fix that with a guard clause:

```
def each_rec
  return @myrecs.each unless block_given?

  @myrecs.each(&Proc.new)
end
```

and can now use it just like `each`:

```
x = MyClass.new
x.each_rec { |r| p r }
x.each_rec.with_index { |r, i| p [r, i] }
```

Comment: While this used to be a good idea, and I've used this very approach many times before, it's worth noting that Ruby 2.7 will [warn you about using this approach](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/09/02/ruby-2-7-proc-without-block-warning.html). This is probably in anticipation of changing how `Proc.new` works in the future.

Comment: @tadman : Actually, I see the warning already in 2.6.4. The article you are linking to, mentions a function named `proc`, which seems to behave like `Proc.new`. I can verify in my Ruby 2.6.4., that this function indeed seems to exist, but [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/) don't seem to know this method. Do you know where I can find about it?

Comment: @user1934428 If you're wondering where to look, Ruby methods that are "universal" tend to live in `Kernel`, which [this one does as well](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-proc). It's a wrapper for `Proc.new`.

Comment: @tadman: Thank you. It is strange, that - differently to the other `Kernel` methods (such as `puts`), `proc` does not show up when we search for it [using the search fields of the Core definition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/)

Comment: it shows up for me when I search it on the linked page, down near the bottom in the instance (**#**) methods, just a lot more class and instance methods show up because you get everything from classes like `Process` and the `Proc` class